# What is this grammatical structure called?

Tags: adjuncts

I noticed that there is sentence construct that starts with an adjective, something like this:

> Ready to race, John started the car.
>
> John, ready to race, started the car.

I looked at some resources [here](http://www.chompchomp.com/terms/relativeclause.htm) and noticed that it's neither a relative clause (which should have a relative pronoun) nor an adjective phrase.

What is that structure, if I'm correct that it's indeed grammatical, called?

Comment: In addition to what is explained in the answer below, these are also **appositions**.

Comment: Hmm, I have always thought that appositions are only for two noun phrases placed next to each other. So that applies for noun phrase-relative clause construct?

Comment: There is a discussion you might find helpful in [this article on ELU](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/137883/sentence-fragments-as-modifiers-self-sacrifice-incarnate-the-10th-doctor-wave). Cerberus gives a comprehensive answer, and variations in terminology are explored.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth: Haha I remember that discussion now. You wouldn't believe how long I had tabs open in my browser to research the various uses of the word; I only closed them recently.

Comment: @Cerberus: Absolutely.

Comment: So, do you think this question should be closed due to being a dup to the linked question? Or does anyone want to offer alternative answer?

Comment: How many alternatives do you want? John Lawler said that the terms suggested weren't wrong, but weren't universally accepted either. There aren't any that are; even 'absolute construction', and 'apposition', are used differently by different linguists.

Comment: Hmm, I see. I never formally studied linguistics, I thought there is a universally accepted set of propositions for each construct, like the one I presented here. So do you think there exists a term for this which is familiar to more linguists? Or perhaps you can complete the answer by listing the possibilities of terms by which this construct is called, and why such terms exist.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth: ...but surely noöne would call this *ready to race* an absolute construction!

Comment: [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Absolute_construction) (with references) does:  [An absolute construction] ... can be a non-finite clause that is subordinate in form and modifies an entire sentence, an adjective [/adjectival phrase] or possessive pronoun standing alone without a modified substantive, or a transitive verb when its object is implied but not stated. >> examples: · Hair streaming in the wind, she rode flat out across the field.
· Mortified, he could not run out of the way of the troll.
· Ready to race, John started the car.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> 1) *Ready to race,* John started the car.
>
> 2) John, *ready to race,* started the car.

The expression *"ready to race"* is an **adjective phrase.** It is functioning as a **predicative adjunct,** and its predicand is the noun "John".

Consider:

- John is *[ready to race].*
- John is *[ready].*
- John is *[tall].*

The above three examples are copular clauses, where the expression in brackets is the *predicative complement*, and the predicand is the subject "John".

In your two original examples, "John" has the property "ready to race" ascribed to it.

NOTE: The terminology in this post is supposedly consistent with that used in the 2002 reference grammar by Huddleston and Pullum et al., *The Cambridge Grammar of the English Language* (CGEL). Related pages: 262-3 ([30.ii] *"[Angry at this deception,] Kim stormed out of the room"*), 529-31, 541, 545-6 ([29]).

Comment: @justhalf By some people. Don't take everything you read as (1) authoritative (though I'm sure F.E. is correctly using CGEL's terminology here), (2) universally accepted / adopted even if coming from such a respected source as CGEL. John Lawler makes this point.

Comment: This stuff is hardly ELL.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth: Thanks for your input. I thought this is too basic for ELU. Do you think this should be migrated? And actually I read the Wikipedia entry on adjuncts, at least it gives more light to what I'm looking for compared to what I've searched so far.

Comment: @justhalf It's been covered there before, as the link above shows. There are often (typically subtly) different approaches in the analyses of these fairly complex structures (Is whiz-deletion a valid explanation? For all cases? ...), and different terminology (because of different emphases required by the different explanations, or merely partiality).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/16838/discussion-between-justhalf-and-edwin-ashworth).

Comment: @EdwinAshworth I agree about ELL (mostly), but anything like this on ELU'll just get migrated here, because the mentality there is "I understand this sentence, so what's the fuss about" ... (sighs)

Answer (score 1):

The problem is where you find it in traditional grammars. Most likely in the chapter participle constructions. There are two possibilities to derive the above construction:

1 John was ready to race and started the car.

2 As John was ready to race he started the car.

In both cases you can shorten the first part of the two sentences by using a participle construction:

3 Being ready to race John started the car.

This is a stylistic device to give more variety to sentence structures.
If the participle construction contains "being" it is mostly dropped 
as "being" has almost no meaning or is self-evident.

Any sentence or subordinate clause can be shortened and changed into a participle construction anď added to another sentence.